# Sending Intent from View to Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Intent class has [`getSourceBouds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSourceBounds%28%29) method.Documents say:

> Get the bounds of the sender of this intent, in screen coordinates.
>   This can be used as a hint to the receiver for animations and the
>   like. Null means that there is no source bounds.

My question is in about `sender of this intent`.Really it seems that only `RemoteViews` can be an "intent sender" which appears in screen.I saw [`IntentSender`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.html) but Instances of this class can not be made directly, but rather must be created from an existing PendingIntent with PendingIntent.getIntentSender() and so I guess that we can not see any instance of IntentSender in the screen.

Finally,Can we use any other thing that appears in Scren(for example `view`) as "sender of intent"  in which getSourceBounds does not return null for it's intent?